# TypeError: "<” not supported between instances of "str' and "int" even though i typecasted both into int data type

Tags: python, typeerror

```
for row in reader:
    if OverseasAirport == row[0]:
        distance_required = row[2]
        int(distance_required)
        for aircraft in aircrafts:
            if aircraft_type in aircraft:
                distance_possible = aircraft[2]
                int(distance_possible)
                if distance_possible < distance_required:
                print("Hi")
```

I tried using this small part of my code, expecting it to allow me to use distance_possible < distance_required but instead it came up with this type error for the values from the lists i used both of them are integers and even when i typecasted to integer to make sure it works it didn't

reader list:

```
JFK,John F Kennedy International,5326,5486
ORY,Paris-Orly,629,379
MAD,Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas,1428,1151
AMS,Amsterdam Schiphol,526,489
CAI,Cairo International,3779,3584
```

aircrafts list:

```
aircrafts = [["Large narrow body", 7, 5600, 220, 10],
             ["Medium narrow body", 8, 2650, 180, 8],
             ["Medium wide body", 5, 4050, 406, 14]]`
```

Comment: No you didn't. The type cast does not work in-place. You need `distance_possible = int(distance_possible)`. Same with `distance_required`

Comment: `distance_required = int(row[2])`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `int()` does not convert. You need to save the result into a variable:

```py
for row in reader:
    if OverseasAirport == row[0]:
        distance_required = row[2]
        distance_required  = int(distance_required)  # <<<
        for aircraft in aircrafts:
            if aircraft_type in aircraft:
                distance_possible = aircraft[2]
                distance_possible  = int(distance_possible)  # <<<
                if distance_possible < distance_required:
                    print("Hi")
```